# Vtiger web services sync operation - parameter syncType not working

Tags: vtiger

I am trying to using the Vtiger 6 web services with the operation sync.

According to this the [Vtiger team](http://lists.vtigercrm.com/pipermail/vtigercrm-developers/2012-July/022510.html):

> In 5.4.0 we have added another parameter 'syncType' which lets you
>   control the type of synchronization i.e. user level or application
>   level. Pass value as 'application' to this parameter.

But this parameter is ignored.

I am using it as `syncType=application`.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the parameter `syncType` is completely ignored and it does not manage to land in the function `vtws_sync` because it's striped out by the Operation Manager in `sanitizeOperation`.

Basically this is not defined as a web service parameter for the operation `sync`, in the table `vtiger_ws_operation_parameters`.

If you want to use it, you need to add it manually.

```
INSERT INTO  `vtigercrm6`.`vtiger_ws_operation_parameters` (
`operationid` ,
`name` ,
`type` ,
`sequence`
)
VALUES (
'6',  'syncType',  'String',  '3'
);
```